# Android: Why does my String value not persist when I rotate Android device? However the countdown portion does

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am extending the Application class to do 2 things. 1) Make onPause() stop the CounterThread until onResume() is pressed. 2) To make the threads continue working while I change orientation of the phone from portrait mode to landscape. Both of the above statements work, however the MakingFileThread when it returns a string value to set the TextView does not persist the orientation changes. Help!!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView mText;
private EditText mUserInput;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    mUserInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    MyApplication app = (MyApplication)getApplication();
    app.pause(null);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication app = (MyApplication)getApplication();
    app.resume(this);
}

public void button_handler(View v){
    String val = mUserInput.getText().toString();
    String file = "myfile.txt";
    MyApplication app = (MyApplication)getApplication();
    app.MakeFileThread(val,file);
    app.startCounterThread();
}

public void updateCountDown(final int seconds){
    String secondText = String.valueOf(seconds);
    mText.setText(secondText);
}

public void updateFileOutput(final String userText){
    mText.setText(userText);
}
```

}

```
public class CounterApplication extends Application {
private MainActivity currentActivity = null;
private CounterThread myThread;


public synchronized void resume(MainActivity update){
    this.currentActivity = update;
    myThread.interrupt();
}

public synchronized void pause(MainActivity update){
    this.currentActivity = update;
    myThread.interrupt();
}

public synchronized void update(final long seconds){

        Runnable notifyAction = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            if(currentActivity != null){
                currentActivity.updateResult(seconds);
            }
        }
    };
    currentActivity.runOnUiThread(notifyAction);
}


public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    myThread = new CounterThread();
    myThread.start();
}

private class CounterThread extends  Thread{
    private long seconds = 0;
    private boolean running = false;

    @Override
    public void run(){

       while(true){

           try{
               Thread.sleep(running?1000:100000);
           }
           catch(InterruptedException e){
                running = !running;
           }
           if(interrupted()){
               running = !running;
           }
           if(running){
               update(++seconds);
           }

       }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, this might help you, add the following line in your manifest file for the activities you need to work in both portrait and landscape:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: hmm Thanks! Will try that! I found that android:freezesText="true" does the trick!

Comment: Also notice how the layout *doesn't* update with the answer, so when you start the activity in landscape and rotate to portrait, the toolbar will keep original 48dp height instead of updating to 56dp and bigger font size. It's amazing how `configChanges` still manages to pop up in 2015...